# LeaveOneOut() - Key Error in an SVM Classifier

Tags: python, svm, leave-one-out

I am working with a csv file: 39 participants (rows) each having values for 30 features (columns). I am trying to implement LeaveOneOut() using the below code. I am getting a key error... Any help would be appreciated!

```
# code
X = df.drop(labels=['Diagnosis'], axis=1) # dropped diagnosis 

Y = df['Diagnosis'].values
Y = Y.astype('int') 

loo = LeaveOneOut()
for train, test in loo.split(X, Y):
    X_train, X_test = X[train], X[test]
    Y_train, Y_test = Y[train], Y[test]

svm = SVC(kernel='linear')
svm.fit(X_train,Y_train)
pred_svm = svm.predict(X_test)
print(classification_report(Y_test, pred_svm))
print(confusion_matrix(Y_test, pred_svm))
```

Comment: What is the  error and also can you share the your implementation of LeaveOneOut if the problem is caused by that?

Comment: The error reads: raise KeyError(f"None of [{key}] are in the [{axis_name}]")
KeyError: "None of [Int64Index([ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17,\n... When I put a print(X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test) function below my 'for' loop, it gives this error again and no splits are printed. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

If you can share what is the result of the loo I can answer more accurately but as far as I understand it is a list of indexes instead of a boolean mask therefore you can change your code like this.

```
for train, test in loo.split(X, Y):
    X_train, X_test = X.loc[train].copy(), X.loc[test].copy()
    Y_train, Y_test = Y[train], Y[test]
```

Comment: Thank you, although this does now split the training and testing data appropriately, the new warning message is: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame. The confusion matrix produced is all 1's. Thank you again for the help, I am new to this

Comment: you just have to copy the dataframes. I am editing the answer

Comment: Sorry, this did not work. I have thought of some other solutions I can try instead! Thank you again for the head start!